# what is simplify, of $\sin^{-1}\tanh\theta=?$

Tags: calculus

can anyone **simplify**,  $\sin^{-1}\tanh\theta=?$ in a better equation?

Comment: i see no equation

Comment: I think, you missed an $=$-sign and something on the right hand side of the equation.

Comment: and i see an expression

Comment: @Dominic Michaelis  can solve it $\sin^{-1}\tanh\theta=?$

Comment: nope ? is not in the image of $\sin^{-1}$ i am afraid

Comment: equal to what?...

Comment: I think you mean *simplify*, not *solve*. Come on guys, cut him some slack.

Comment: @Rahul: The questions are just the socratic method: if you have difficulty even stating what it is you're trying to do, that's a severe impediment to actually doing it, or understanding a solution someone presents you! Not to mention there's another 'obvious' putative interpretation besides simplification: that there is actually something on the right hand side and he wants to solve for $\theta$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the Gudermannian function. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function) or [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gudermannian.html).

Comment: ok thank you.
so
$\sinh^{-1}\tan x$ is The inverse Gudermannian function,

Answer (score 0):

$\sin^{-1}\tanh x=2{\tan^{-1} \tanh x} \cosh x \sqrt {\operatorname{sech}^2 x}$